# Custom sort for histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

After looking at countless questions and answers on how to do custom sorting of the bars in bar charts (or a histogram in my case) it seemed the answer was to sort the dataframe as desired and then do the plot, only to find that the plot ignores the data and blithely sorts alphabetically. There does not seem to be a simple option to turn sorting off, or just supply a list to the plot to sort by.

Here's my sample code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

diamonds = pd.DataFrame({'carat': [0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22],
                   'cut'  : ['Ideal', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'],
                   'color': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'J', 'E'], 
                   'clarity': ['SI2', 'SI1', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VS2'],
                   'depth': [61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.8, 65.1],
                   'table': [55, 61, 65, 57, 61],
                   'price': [326, 326, 327, 336, 337]})



diamonds.set_index('cut', inplace=True)
cuts_order = ['Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal']
df = pd.DataFrame(diamonds.loc[cuts_order].carat)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
plt.hist(df.cut);
```

This returns the 'cuts' in alphabetical order but not as sorted in the data. I was quite excited to have figured out a clever way of sorting the data, so much bigger the disappointment the plot is ignorant.

What is the most straightforward way of doing this?
Here's what I get with the above code:

[image: Wrong result]

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the idea of a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and would rather like to plot a bar plot?! `plt.bar(df.cut, df.carat)`

Comment: Well your code works for me, I have one bar for each `cut` in this order `'Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal'`

Comment: You don't need to prepare a separate dataframe just for plotting: `diamonds.plot.bar(use_index=True, y='carat')`. It plots your data in the original order

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Possibly, as I mentally equated the 'cuts' with bins. The plt.bar plot gives me the exact same wrong sequence however, and not the bar heights based on a simple record count per category.

Comment: Record count per category? You have exactly one record per category, right? Can you describe clearly what the desired outcome is?

Comment: That was helpful as it got me thinking in a different direction. Looks like a histogram is the wrong approach, not least because the bars refuse any attempt at being ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Update of your code with the answers in the comments:

```py
In [1]:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

diamonds = pd.DataFrame({'carat': [0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22],
                   'cut'  : ['Ideal', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'],
                   'color': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'J', 'E'], 
                   'clarity': ['SI2', 'SI1', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VS2'],
                   'depth': [61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.8, 65.1],
                   'table': [55, 61, 65, 57, 61],
                   'price': [326, 326, 327, 336, 337]})


diamonds.set_index('cut', inplace=True)
cuts_order = ['Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal']
df = pd.DataFrame(diamonds.loc[cuts_order].carat)
df.plot.bar(use_index=True, y='carat')

Out [1]:
```

[image]

Comment: What is the negative vote for, something I misunderstood in the issue ?

Comment: Wasn't from me. This is moving in the right direction as the sorting works! How do you get the bars to show record count per category though, as in a histogram?

Comment: Why does 'use_index=True' work with plot.bar and not plt.bar?

Comment: See here: (Doc plt from matplotlib pyplot) [https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html]

(Doc plot from pandas) [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot]

Comment: use_index is an argument of plot, and just do not exist for plt

Answer (score 0):

A histogram was not the right plot here. With the following code the bars, sorted as desired, are created:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

diamonds = pd.DataFrame({'carat': [0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22],
                   'cut'  : ['Ideal', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'],
                   'color': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'J', 'E'], 
                   'clarity': ['SI2', 'SI1', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VS2'],
                   'depth': [61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.8, 65.1],
                   'table': [55, 61, 65, 57, 61],
                   'price': [326, 326, 327, 336, 337]})
cuts_order = ['Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal']

c_classes = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(ordered = True, categories = cuts_order)
diamonds['cut'] = diamonds['cut'].astype(c_classes)
to_plot = diamonds.cut.value_counts(sort=False)

plt.bar(to_plot.index, to_plot.values)
```

Side note, matplotlib 2.1.0 behaves differently because plt.bar will blithely ignore the sort order that it is given, I can only confirm this works with 3.0.3 (and hopefully higher).

[image: Sorted bar chart]

I also tried sorting the data by index but this does not take effect for some reason, looks like value_counts(sort=False) does not return values in the order it is found in the data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

diamonds = pd.DataFrame({'carat': [0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22],
                   'cut'  : ['Ideal', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'],
                   'color': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'J', 'E'], 
                   'clarity': ['SI2', 'SI1', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VS2'],
                   'depth': [61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.8, 65.1],
                   'table': [55, 61, 65, 57, 61],
                   'price': [326, 326, 327, 336, 337]})
diamonds.set_index('cut', inplace=True)
cuts_order = ['Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal']
diamonds = diamonds.loc[cuts_order]
to_plot = diamonds.index.value_counts(sort=False)

plt.bar(to_plot.index, to_plot.values)
```

Seaborn is also an option as it potentially removes the dependency on the available matplotlib version:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
%matplotlib inline

diamonds = pd.DataFrame({'carat': [0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22],
                   'cut'  : ['Ideal', 'Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'],
                   'color': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'J', 'E'], 
                   'clarity': ['SI2', 'SI1', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VS2'],
                   'depth': [61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.8, 65.1],
                   'table': [55, 61, 65, 57, 61],
                   'price': [326, 326, 327, 336, 337]})
cuts_order = ['Fair','Good','Very Good','Premium','Ideal']

c_classes = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(ordered = True, categories = cuts_order)
diamonds['cut'] = diamonds['cut'].astype(c_classes)
to_plot = diamonds.cut.value_counts(sort=False)

ax = sb.barplot(data = diamonds, x = to_plot.index, y = to_plot.values)
```